# On the continuity condition of the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I have to show that $\partial_\mu j^\mu = 0$ for the four-current $j^\mu = \frac{i}{2m}\left(\phi^*\partial^\mu\phi - \phi\:\partial^\mu\phi^*\right)$.
Using the Leibniz rule, one gets to
$$\partial_\mu j^\mu = \frac{i}{2m}\left((\partial_\mu\phi^*\!)\partial^\mu\phi + \phi^*\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi - (\partial_\mu \phi)\partial^\mu\phi^*-\phi\;\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi^*\right)$$

Now, using the Klein-Gordon equation, it is easy to verify that the second and fourth terms cancel each other.
The first and third ones should be equal (and hence cancel) as well, but I don't understand why. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: You have to show that $\partial_\nu A\partial^\nu B=\partial^\nu A\partial_\nu B$. It is just a matter of raising and lowering indices and has nothing to do with (relativistic) QM.

Comment: @TobiasFünke does it follow from the metric tensor properties, namely $g_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}$ and $g_{\mu\nu}=g^{\nu\mu}$?